# Batch Process mp3s with Dynamic Filename

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I am currently extracting mp3 decibel information using this ffmpeg command:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=*title*.mp3,astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0 1>log.csv
```

Unfortunately, I can only process one mp3 file at a time as I need to specify the filename each time. I also have a static export csv filename of "log.csv". Is there anyway I can modify this command to batch process all mp3 files in one folder and export the data with the same filename?

Answer (score 0):

`for /R %I in (*.mp3) do command "%I" >> log.csv`

In a batch file, you will need to double the percent signs.  `>` overwrites a file, `>>` appends.

/R is recursive.